# Java form based authentication get the original request

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web.xml, form-authentication

I am using form based authentication, and I would like to get the original request in my `login.jsp`, to display my page based on the request.

I have tried using the `request.getRequestURI()  request.getRequestURL()`
but I am only getting the information from the request of the login page
so is there any way to get the original request?

this is my `web.xml`

`<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>My Program</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/pages/login/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/pages/login/login.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>`

Comment: Why not just pass in a forward path? From any page which requires authentication, if a user isn't logged in, send them to the login page, and pass the current path + args, URL-encoded, as a `forward` parameter. Have your login action then do a redirect to `siteURL + "/" + forward` on successful authentication, and you're good. Obviously this works better with GETs, and is easier with a framework like Struts which lets you install filters, but I digress.

Comment: Also, if you're using Spring, by any chance, then you should look into Spring Security.

Comment: Can you provide your JSP & Servlet (or Controller) code ?

Comment: The form authentication is configured in the `web.xml`, so the first place i could write code is in the `login.jsp`

Comment: Question: do you want to forward to the original request after login, or do you want to change the contents/looks of your `login.jsp` based upon the original request?

Comment: i want to change the look and structure of the page